# Retrieving product attributes in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I'm interested in getting frontend input strings. I understand that there are better ways other than checking for the "frontend_input" key, but I'm wanting a proof of concept. Here's my code:

```
$attributesForUpload = [];
$collection = $this->_filter->getCollection($this->_collectionFactory->create());
foreach ($collection->getItems() as $product) {
   $productId = $product->getId();
   $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
   foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
       $data = $attribute->getData();
       if (isset($data['frontend_input'])) {
           if ($data['frontend_input'] === 'text' || $data['frontend_input'] === 'textarea') {
               $attributeCode = $data['attribute_code'];
               var_dump($attributeCode);
               $translatableValue = $product->getData($attributeCode);
               var_dump($translatableValue);
               $attributesForUpload[$productId][$attributeCode] = $translatableValue;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Among others, product name, description, and short description are all null. Only the SKU is being returned. I'm wondering why this is since I specifically save them in the UI; I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace this

```
$this->_filter->getCollection($this->_collectionFactory->create());
```

with this

```
$this->_filter->getCollection($this->_collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the product maybe wasn't really the full product. I had to inject an \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository object into my constructor and call:

```
$theProduct = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
```

Then the attributes weren't null anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a product custom attribute you can access it like this:

```
/** @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface */
$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);

$myCustomAttribute = $product->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute')->getValue();
```